# How to use Radio Button values in a button URL?

Tags: javascript

I have a form with a few radio buttons and I want to use the value of the radio button selection to change what url you go to when you click a button.

```
<input type="radio" name="Server" value="ftp://one.com" checked>One
<input type="radio" name="Server" value="ftp://two.com">Two


<button type="button" name="" onClick="location.href='document.getElementsByName("Server").checked + "/file.ext"'">Download
```

I want to select the FTP server with the radio button and change the download link of the button.

Comment: Where are you having trouble with this? Can you post the code you've tried so far (or how you were thinking about going about it if you're not quite sure how to code it)?

Comment: I posted the code but it just showed up as text until I put spaces in

Comment: there's a typo on getElementsByName and your html is not valid. could you complete your code? That will help

Comment: Fixed the typo and that is all of my html. What is not valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function getServer() {
    var servers = document.getElementsByName("Server");
    for(var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
        if (servers[i].checked) {
            return servers[i].value;
        }
    }
    return '';
}
</script>

<input type="radio" name="Server" value="ftp://one.com" checked>One
<input type="radio" name="Server" value="ftp://two.com">Two


<button type="button" id="courseware" onClick="location.href= getServer() + '/file.ext'">Download
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be

```
document.getElementsByName("Server").checked
```

You're missing an 'e'...